# Populate select box depending on choice of different select box (php / ajax)

Tags: php

Basically I have two forms
The first form Is a simple select box which submits it's value to be processed and inserted into a database (mysql)
However on the same page I have a second form with a select box which will be auto populated with the results from the database(ajax / php), depending on which option was chosen from the first forms select box

So anyway I need some way to store the first select box's chosen value in a variable without submitting the form

Comment: What does your current code look like? We can't really offer improvements without seeing where you are at currently.

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html  ?

Comment: mantigatos link is of great help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try.

```
$('#firstForm').submit(function(){
var firstValue = $('#firstForm select').val()
 //do your ajax call.

return false //then return false or 
            //preventDefault should keep the form from submitting
})
```